# How can I mass create a drawing for laser cutting (DXF, DWG, etc.) with different QR codes

Tags: dxf, dwg, ezdxf, lasercutting

I am trying to cut some tags with a laser cutter. Every tag that I cut should have a different QR code.

The cut pattern is the same for all, but I need a way to create an image of a QR code that can work in a loop. In total there will be about 80 tags, so 80 different QR codes is needed.

I have tried thinking of a way to draw it so that I can generate QR codes automatically.
I have thought of using HTML with SVGs+image, Python with ezDXF (not used that lib. before, so maybe there is something here), Excel with maybe some plugin for QR codes, and I have looked at Adobe Illustrator to see if I was able to automate things there. All attempts were without luck